# Bootstrap 4 tab-panes. Change two panes with one nav-link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get two different cards to update their active tab-pane using one nav-link.
Here is my code. As you can see, I have one card that has act info and one that has the corresponding video in it. When I click to see the other act info, I want the video to also change (at the moment there is no second video - it just says 'stuff number 2'

```
<div class="row pt-5" id="acts">
        <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
            <div class="card">
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#act1" role="tab">Take Five</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#act2" role="tab">Thank You For Your Consideration</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="act1" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <h3 class="card-title">Take Five</h3>
                            <p class="card-text">Do you also have trouble getting out of bed? Working 9 to 5, the same routine every day.. “Take Five” is about one of those days,  a light hearted piece full of absurdness and acrobatics. People of all ages can enjoy the 7- minute act,  let Ida surprise you!</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="act2" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <h3 class="card-title">Thank You For Your Consideration</h3>
                                        <p class="card-text">What do you write in a letter when you apply for a job? Everybody has been there, behind a computer screen, mind blank. It sounds too pretentious or too insecure. If only they would see the real you. But if that’s a good idea.. An act about struggles that everyone has experienced, brought with humour, brutal honesty and creativity in movement. Ida’s genuine story is a 6 minute text-based circus performance.</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <img src="" alt="TYFYC" class="img-fluid img-rounded">
                                    </div>
                                </div>j
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 offset-md-2">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="act1" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/220114759"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="act2" role="tabpanel">
                        Stuff number 2
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to do this without using a javascript `.addClass('active')`?

Comment: it can't be done without javascript  or jquery